# Заполнить недостающие элементы коллекции

Tags: java, алгоритм

Есть коллекция строк к которой применена лексикографическая сортировка, то есть :

```
ABC1
ABC1\AA1\B1
ABC2\AA1
ABC2\AA1\B1
```

Но есть места где существуют пропуски:

```
ABC1
... пропущено ABC1\AA1
ABC1\AA1\B1
ABC1\AA2
... пропущено ABC2
ABC2\AA1
ABC2\AA1\B1
```

Помогите написать метод который будет  добавлять в коллекцию недостающие элементы.

Comment: приложите пример вашего кода

Comment: Ну собственно для каждого элемента метод должен проверять наличие элемента с "откушенным" последним уровнем. При отсутствии - добавлять и проверять уже его (т.е. снова "откусывать" и проверять, а при отсутствии добавлять), а при наличии - обрабатывать следующий элемент...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<String> out = new TreeSet<>();
        List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add("ABC1");
        list.add("ABC1\\AA1\\B1");
        list.add("ABC2\\AA1");
        list.add("ABC2\\AA1\\B1");
        String last = "";
        for (String current : list) {
            if (!last.equals("") && !current.matches("^" + last)) {
                temp.add(current);
            }
            last = current;
        }
        for (String line : temp) {
            String[] splitted = line.split("\\\\");
            String append = "";
            for (String element : Arrays.asList(splitted)) {
                append += "\\" + element;
                out.add(append.replaceAll("^\\\\", ""));
            }
        }
        for(String s:out){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
ABC1
ABC1\AA1
ABC1\AA1\B1
ABC2
ABC2\AA1
ABC2\AA1\B1
```

Осталось перевести в List и отсортировать заново, если нужно

Comment: Спасибо большое. А подскажите пожалуйста что означает `^`?

Comment: @Павел это символ начала строки в регулярном выражении